# Members Group Access login

Tags: members, registration, groups

I've made 2 new Member Groups, Ouders and Kids.
Both are base on the Members group.

I've a Template Group nieuws. Access for this index is only for Member Group Ouders.

I've a Template Group activities. Access for this index is only for Member Group Kids.

In my template nieuws/index I have this code:

```
 {if logged_in}

 {exp:channel:entries channel="nieuws" disable="categories|member_data"}
 .... 
{/exp:channel:entries}


 {/if}


 {if logged_out} 
{exp:member:login_form}
         <p> <label>gebruikersnaam</label><br> <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="formfield" maxlength="32" size="25">
         </p>
         <p> <label>wachtwoord</label><br> <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="formfield" maxlength="32" size="25">
         </p>

         <p><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="LOGIN"></p>   
{/exp:member:login_form} 
{/if}
```

In my template activities/index I have this code:

```
{if logged_in}

{exp:channel:entries channel="activities" disable="categories|member_data"}
....
{/exp:channel:entries}


{/if}


{if logged_out}
{exp:member:login_form}
        <p>
<label>gebruikersnaam</label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" class="formfield" maxlength="32" size="25">
        </p>
        <p>
<label>wachtwoord</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="formfield" maxlength="32" size="25">
        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="LOGIN"></p>

{/exp:member:login_form}
{/if}
```

If I login with the username/password from a Kids Member Group I get access to both templates (nieuws and activities) when a Kids member should only have access to the activities template. If I login as a Ouders member I get access also to both template.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need an Add-on to achieve this.

Francois

Comment: Are you allowing the member to be logged in after registration?

Comment: @BhashkarYadav I made a mistake in my message, I change it. Read "If I login with..." instead of "If I register..." Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify **each** of your conditionals surrounding the channel entries tag to include group info.

```
{if logged_in_group_id == '1' OR logged_in_group_id == '7'}
  <!-- Enter in correct id for member group, including any admin groups. -->
  {exp:channel:entries ...}
{/if}
```

You can also redirect someone who went to the wrong page. For example, if a logged in kid goes to the nieuws page, you can redirect them to the activities page by adding this to the nieuws template.

```
{if logged_in_group_id == '7'}{redirect="/activities"}{/if}
```

Comment: Of course, it sound very logical. I still have so many things to learn, it keeps me young. Stephen, thanks a lot Francois

Comment: Francois, glad it helped.